# Three.js | Vertex's distance from center doesn't change after applying displacement map on sphereGeometry

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to calculate the distance (from origin) of displaced vertices after applying displacement map on a sphere geometry(positioned at origin only).

As the displacement map changes the position of the vertex, the distance should differ in both the cases ( before and after applying displacement map ), but somehow the distance from center of the sphere ( here origin ) doesn't change.

Any views on this? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: When you say displacement map, are you referring to a texture, like a bump map?

Comment: @TheJim01 Yes. The displacement texture is an image where the value of each pixel (white being the highest) is mapped against, and repositions, the vertices of the mesh.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible given where displacement mapping fits into the graphics pipeline. You essentially "send off" all your data into shaders, and that's where the displacement mapping occurs. That's why it's efficient but also not accessible. If you need something more accessible, you'll need to write some JS that operates on your vertices beforehand, but it will not be nearly as performant. You could also blend the two methods by creating a dynamic displacement map. It all depends on context, which isn't clear in your question. Why do you need to calculate the vertex distance after you've applied the map? In making the displacement map, you are directly setting the position of vertices, and could calculate the distance from origin just based on the original vertices and reading the displacement map.

Comment: I've placed different geometries at different vertices of sphere which change with respect to distance from the actual surface of sphere(or origin) after applying displacement map

Comment: It's hard to answer any more specifically without an example. Consider adding an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your displacement map does not affect the geometry as it is defined. Instead, it affects it at render time, where the shaders use the map to adjust the vertex positions and fragment shading. This information is not shared back to the main program.

I believe the easiest way to get what you want is to calculate it manually. This means that for each vertex, you would look at its UV coordinate, read the value of that coordinate from the displacement map image, and then perform the calculation for how the displacement value affects the vertex. You already know that all your vertices are a certain radius from the origin, so this is easy:

```
totalDistance = radius + ( displacementRange * displacementFactor )
```

You can also pull values closer to the center by segmenting your displacement values (e.g. `1` is full push, `0.5` is no change, `0` is full pull):

```
totalDistance = radius + ( displacementRange * displacementFactor * ((displacementFactor < 0.5)? -1 : 1))
```